# Disposable Camera left in the heat

Tags: 35mm, fujifilm, heat, disposable-cameras

I ordered disposable
cameras, and they left them
at my mailbox in 110 degree weather.
I picked them up 4 hrs later.
They were inside a
cardboard box with stuffing
so the actual cameras just
felt warm. And they were also inside their product box, wrapped in their aluminum wrapping. They were not in direct sunlight either. Is the film inside
them ok? I’m supposed to take them on my trip to Europe :(

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they will be fine. Film is sensitive to heat, but for periods as short as a few hours, there will be no noticeable deterioration. People sometimes fret over this issue as if film were a dairy product; it's not *that* sensitive.

But, don't expect fantastic results from disposable cameras in any case. They are fun, but they use cheap, slow plastic lenses, and the film inside is not as sensitive as a digital sensor. Use them in good light (outdoors), and you should get some pleasing results.

One more thing - do not put these cameras in your checked luggage. Keep them in your hand luggage. Checked luggage is scanned with X-rays that are strong enough to damage film inside. Hand luggage also goes through X-ray scanners, but at a lower level.

Comment: +1 for **Avoiding X-ray inspection of checked luggage** Also, take more care with your exposed films than your unexposed ones. After all, they're not replaceable.

Comment: @Stan On the other hand, if they've already been fogged by an X-ray machine before exposure, they're still fogged after exposure. Fogging before use is only less severe if one realizes they've been fogged and thus does not use them at all.